# Automatically add a product to the cart when visite it in woocommerce store

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I would like to add a feature that enables adding any product that is visited to the cart and emptying the cart automatically and emptying it from the cart in the event of leaving the product page.

The following code is related to adding a product if you visit a specific page on WordPress:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'bbloomer_add_product_to_cart_on_page_id_load' );
  
function bbloomer_add_product_to_cart_on_page_id_load() {
          
   $product_id = 14837;
 
   if ( is_page( 19473 ) ) {    
      WC()->cart->empty_cart();
      WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id ); 
   }
    
}
```

But I want a way to make the code work when visiting the product page without selecting a specific product page or selecting a normal wordpress page

I tried using this code but it doesn't work

```
add_action( 'wp', 'bbloomer_add_product_to_cart_on_page_id_load' );

function bbloomer_add_product_to_cart_on_page_id_load() {

    global $product;

$product_id=$product->id;
$slug = $product->get_slug();

if ( is_page( $slug ) ) {  
WC()->cart->empty_cart();
WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution

```html
add_action( 'wp', 'bbloomer_add_product_to_cart_on_page_id_load' );
function bbloomer_add_product_to_cart_on_page_id_load() {
 if ( is_product() ) { 
   $product = wc_get_product();
   $id = $product->get_id();
   $product_id = $id;

   if ($id ==$product_id ) {   
      WC()->cart->empty_cart();
      WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id ); 
        
    }else{  WC()->cart->empty_cart(); }
   
    
 }
}
```